# Passing data from controller to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a View for creating a new Item. Item consists of just two properties - Name and Group.

So I want a view that has one textbox and one DropDownList. I am using DropDownList because user shouldn't be able to type whatever he wants in the Group field - there are already some predefined groups and View should enable the user to just pick one group.

I have ItemModel class that has two properties - Name (string) and GroupId (int). My view is strongly typed to ItemModel.

My questions is following: how should I pass a list of valid groups that should be presented as a choice inside DropDownList? Should I create another property inside ItemModel just for that, or maybe pass it using ViewBag or do something something else?

Comment: Do you get the groups from a database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you add:

```
ViewBag.MyGroups = new SelectList(db.Groups.Where(t => t.TGroupId == "1").ToList(), "MyGroups", "Description", 1);
```

In the view you add:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyGroups ");
```

Basically, make a new selectionlist and pass it to a ViewBag.

Comment: I know it can be done like that, but I'm wandering if it's the right way of doing it (if you consider MVC design pattern)?